# Using TextSpan to display translation underline

Tags: flutter, text, render, arabic, textspan

I am writing an English to Arabic translation app using Flutter.
I want to display the Arabic translation of each sentence between the lines of the English text (woven together, see attached).
How can I wrap one-line English, then one line Arabic,... and finally wrap remainder last lines without extra line space?

Maybe I can do it but weaving to TextSpans with 2x line space using Stack?

(Text is dummy, don't try to read it!)
[image]

Comment: you have to pass your `TextSpan` to [Text.rich](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/Text.rich.html) constructor

Comment: @pskink Please describe a little more, thanks.

Comment: you are inserting linefeed using \n, but my text should be auto wrapped, depending on font size, one line English, one line Arabic,...

Comment: But then they will not wove together!

Comment: English paragraph starts and wraps at end of line,...
Arabic paragraph starts and is written under first line, but wrapped at end of line, having line space so draws next line under next english line...

Comment: did you find solution yet ?

Comment: yes, stack of 2 Paragraphs, measure them using LayoutBuilder